# nftables dnat forwarding is not working properly

Tags: iptables, systemd, arch-linux, dnat, nftables

Good day,

I am currently migrating from iptables to nftables.
The problem is my systemd containers are running behind NAT, but I want to forward ports like 443 or 80 to them.
There is no error message when I use the following set of commands, but neither do I get to my web server when I use nftables.

Many thanks in advance.

With best regards,
Felix

EDIT.: The problem was solved by the helpful comments. Thank you!

Comment: Please make sure any relevant information is in your question, not linked to an external site. Especially since the external site you linked to is broken.

Comment: just in case, add the nat output chain even if not used, to rule out a current "bug" not very documented but known for long. eg: https://marc.info/?l=netfilter&m=152532769025083&w=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Роман Иванов for useful `nft monitor`.

NAT doesn't work because i use this rule at the end of filter forward:

```
iifname wan0 reject
```

in chain NAT you need rule:

> NAT => PREROUTING

```
nft add rule nat prerouting iifname wan0 tcp dport { 80, 443 } dnat 192.168.0.10
```

in chain FILTER you need rule:

> FILTER => FORWARD

```
nft add rule filter forward iifname wan0 oifname lan0 ip daddr 192.168.0.10 tcp dport { 80, 443 } accept
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps you can take:

1. Type nat hook prerouting priority 0; <-Should be -100 (minus hundred) according to NF_IP_PRI_NAT_DST netfilter constant
2. Use "meta nftrace set 1" in prerouting and "nft monitor" for debug you packet flow
3. Simplest ruleset to isolate problem and make example

I also have not working dnat. From one iface all OK but from other not.

Packets enter prerouting, dnat accepted But nothing happens after this. "Conntrac -E" does not see these packages.